# Hope to know lon lat from drawn line at folium

Tags: python, folium

I need to know longitude and latitude from folium map.
Therefore, I tried export option of folium draw plugins.

```
draw = Draw(export=True,filename='C://Users//Yourname//Desktop//test.geojson')
draw.add_to(m)
```

However it didn't save anything.
Also, if I click the polyline after use draw plugins, it just poped up Javascript Alert.

Summarize it again, I want to know the lon/lat value if I click or draw something on map.

Comment: The draw tool provided by folium is only for adding lines and rectangles on the map, so I don't think it can get latitude and longitude information interactively. I tried the [sample](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/plugin-Draw.ipynb) on this page, and was able to draw a line and save the map after drawing. The saved file contains the latitude and longitude of the starting and ending points. If you need the desired behavior, you may want to consider graphs using plotly's geopandas

Comment: [plotly geopandas](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-mapbox/#lines-on-mapbox-maps-from-geopandas)